# Which Map is good to tag people's home ? I do not see details (i.e. home outlets) in any maps

Tags: dictionary

I want to tag my friends home & my home home, I was wondering which map could be more helpful.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I would recommend [Google Earth](http://www.google.com/earth/index.html) 
It allows you to tag places on the map and it also has many other cool functions such as layers and etc and also the ability to add 3d models!!!

Comment: I want to add map into my web application and allow users to add information into the map and save those into my DB, which opensource map would solve this purpose ?

Comment: @user2425390 google maps should work but don't know if they're open source here is a little tut on how to add custom markers
https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/customizing/custom-markers

Comment: thanks I am quiet new to this, Thanks a ton for your ultra quick  answer.